# (Excel) If cell is greater than <condition> then minus <number>

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I’m creating an excel spreadsheet that contains the following:

- Cell B4: Number that represents Bob’s subcontractor fortnight (earning in 2 weeks) earnings.
- Cell B6: Number that represents Bob’s student allowance a fortnight.
- Cell B5: Display the the total that was subtracted from Bob’s student allowance this specific fortnight.

**Subtraction of allowance:** If bob earn more than $300 as subcontractor his allowance will be reduce by 0,60 cents in each dollar over $300 in his subcontractor earnings.

```
0,60 * (B4-300) = subtraction
```

**Using Excel, what is the formula to calculate the remaining amount in Bob's student allowance?**

*I have tried the below, but it doesn't work.*

```
IF B4>300-60% from B6
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so..

The IF function to calculate B5 (amount to subtract from student allowance)

```
=IF(B4>300;0,6*(B4-300);0)
```

IF Bob earns more than $300 then multiplay 0.6 cents per euro above 300. Else, the subtraction equals $0.

**Using Excel, what is the formula to calculate the remaining amount in Bob's student allowance?**

```
=IF(B4>300;B6-0,6*(B4-300);0)
```

[image]